# install self-compiled libraries in ubuntu

Tags: webkit, kubuntu

Whats the recommended way to install self-compiled libraries? The libraries are supposed to replace existing ubuntu packages. Of course I want that the apt dependencies to be fullfilled. The sources for the libraries are not the ones provided by ubuntu. And I want other software to find the libraries so I would put them into the same path by overwriting existing files provided by the corresponding packages. Is this too dirty? Specifically I want to compile webkit libraries for qt since the ones provided by kubuntu are way too old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldnt mess with the libraries installed by the distro. Esp., you should not replace them with your own version as this can break many things.

You can install your own libraries in a non-system location (side by side install) and use LD_PRELOAD for pre-built binaries or if you are compiling your own apps as well, link them with your libraries.